# List of dict of dict in Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have list of dict of dicts in the following form:

`[{0:{'city':'newyork', 'name':'John', 'age':'30'}},
 {0:{'city':'newyork', 'name':'John', 'age':'30'}},]`

I want to create pandas DataFrame in the following form:

`city     name    age
 newyork   John    30
 newyork   John    30`

Tried a lot but without any success

can you help me?

Comment: the `dict` you have given has only 1 key, will they be having fixed keys or dynamic?

Comment: key is dynamic, increases with the length of dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `concat` and [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
L = [{0:{'city':'newyork', 'name':'John', 'age':'30'}},
 {0:{'city':'newyork', 'name':'John', 'age':'30'}}]

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, orient='index') for x in L])
print (df)
   name age     city
0  John  30  newyork
0  John  30  newyork
```

Solution with multiple keys with new column `id` should be:

```
L = [{0:{'city':'newyork', 'name':'John', 'age':'30'}, 
      1:{'city':'newyork1', 'name':'John1', 'age':'40'}},
     {0:{'city':'newyork', 'name':'John', 'age':'30'}}]

L1 = [dict(v, id=k) for x in L for k, v in x.items()]
print (L1)
[{'name': 'John', 'age': '30', 'city': 'newyork', 'id': 0}, 
 {'name': 'John1', 'age': '40', 'city': 'newyork1', 'id': 1}, 
 {'name': 'John', 'age': '30', 'city': 'newyork', 'id': 0}]
df = pd.DataFrame(L1)
print (df)
  age      city  id   name
0  30   newyork   0   John
1  40  newyork1   1  John1
2  30   newyork   0   John
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from pandas import DataFrame

ldata = [{0: {'city': 'newyork', 'name': 'John', 'age': '30'}},
         {0: {'city': 'newyork', 'name': 'John', 'age': '30'}}, ]

# 根据上面的ldata创建一个Dataframe
df = DataFrame(d[0] for d in ldata)
print(df)
"""
The answer is:
  age     city  name
0  30  newyork  John
1  30  newyork  John
"""
```

Comment: You might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd 
d = [{0:{'city':'newyork', 'name':'John', 'age':'30'}},{0:{'city':'newyork', 'name':'John', 'age':'30'}},]   
df = pd.DataFrame([list(i.values())[0] for i in d])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  age     city  name
0  30  newyork  John
1  30  newyork  John
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing`

Comment: In Python 3, `.values()` returns an iterable, *not* a list, you can't index it. You answer is only valid for Python 2.

Comment: @liliscent. Thanks. Updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
In [41]: df = pd.DataFrame(next(iter(e.values())) for e in l)

In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
  age     city  name
0  30  newyork  John
1  30  newyork  John
```

Answer (score 0):

Came to new solution. Not as straightforward as posted here but works properly

```
L = [{0:{'city':'newyork', 'name':'John', 'age':'30'}},
     {0:{'city':'newyork', 'name':'John', 'age':'30'}}]


df = [L[i][0] for i in range(len(L))]


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df)
```